# Is it possible to show the dataframe row header in vertical?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles, seaborn

I have the code below and it shows both column header and row header as below.

```
styles = [ 
 {'selector': 'th', 
  'props': [('background', 'grey'),  
            ('color', 'white'),('border-style','solid'),('border-width','1px')]}, 
 {'selector': 'td', 
  'props': [('color', 'grey'),('border-style','solid'),('border-width','1px')]}, 
]
foo = pd.Categorical(['a', 'b'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])
bar = pd.Categorical(['d', 'e'], categories=['d', 'e', 'f'])
pd.crosstab(foo, bar).style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

[image]

Is it possible to show the row header in vertical like below?

[image]

Comment: just output html and apply CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary question - can you rotate text?

1. need to format your dataframe so that *row_0* is part of multi index
2. just need to get your CSS selector right to identify the HTML element you want to rotate

The rest of the formatting and selectors can then follow.

```
styles = [ 
{'selector':'tbody>tr:first-child>th:first-child', 'props':[('transform', 'rotate(90deg)'),]},
]
foo = pd.Categorical(['a', 'b'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])
bar = pd.Categorical(['d', 'e'], categories=['d', 'e', 'f'])
df = pd.crosstab(foo, bar)
# need to rebuild index as row_0 needs to be part of multiindex key
ri = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple([df.index.name, v]) for v in df.index.values])
df.set_index(ri).style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

[image]